# how to run exe file in azure data factroy with input parameters?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

i have a console application. i built this application and uploaded it to the Azure  blob storage. Then i run this application Azure data factory pipeline. All are fine but the problem is if i want to add new parameters(get input) to console application how can i do that? Is there any specific way to do it?

```
 {
    "name": "samplebatch",
    "type": "Custom",
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
        "retry": 0,
        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
        "secureOutput": false
    },    
"typeProperties": {
        "command": "SampleApp.exe",
        "folderPath": "customactv2/SampleApp",
        "resourceLinkedService": {
          "referenceName": "StorageLinkedService",
          "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        }
   "linkedServiceName": {
        "referenceName": "dataloadbatchservice",
        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    }
}
```

This is what i have done so far in the data factory pipeline code.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: yes thanks for the reply. Sorry for late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the `extendedProperties` property in `typeProperties`, you could use it.

> User-defined properties that can be passed to the custom application
>   in JSON format so your custom code can reference additional properties

Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity#custom-activity

Sample:https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/blob/master/Samples/ADFv2CustomActivitySample/MyCustomActivityPipeline.json